# The 'Personal hotspot' option is gone from my iPhone 4. Why?

Tags: iphone, tethering

The 'Personal hotspot' option is gone from my iPhone 4. Why? Is there any way to get it back?

Comment: Still not showing :(

Comment: Have you tried the suggestion I mentioned bellow?

Comment: Cellular Data Network is not showing in my iPhone

Comment: When you go to Settings / General / Network, what options do you see?

Comment: Only these http://k.min.us/idE9kTvF1.jpg

Comment: It would appear you are not the only one having this issue? (https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3044480?start=0&tstart=0) Are you running the latest iOS version? Have tried restoring the entire phone from scratch?

Comment: I have updated my iphone iOS to lates using itunes 2 days back

Comment: Upgrading might not be enough, you could try a complete restore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Today I get the option back. After 6 month I found [Onavo](http://www.onavo.com/) app was the reason to disable "personal Hotspot". I just uninstalled it.

http://getsatisfaction.com/onavo/topics/my_personal_hotspot_configuration_has_gone

I wrote an email to Onavo support about it and got this reply

> Dave NOV 09, 2011  |  06:44PM IST Hi Jitendra,
>
> Thanks for replying.
>
> We're sorry to hear that, still trying to find a solution for this.
>   Our team is working on several solutions, will update soon. Regards,
>
> Onavo Support  http://onavo.com

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you have an APN + Username & password set under Settings > General > Network > Cellular Data Network. The bottom option "Internet Tethering" has to be filled in to enable Personal Hotspot.

Apple KB article - [iOS: About cellular data network settings (viewing or editing the APN)](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2283?viewlocale=en_US)

Answer (score 0):

Check Settings > General > Network, or restart the phone.

Comment: Tried as u suggested but problem is still there

Answer (score 0):

Does your carrier require that you pay for this feature?  I don't know how it's handled in India but in the US, the carriers charge extra for this.  Of course, here in Canada, the carriers provide it for free provided your data plan isn't one of the minimal ones.

So perhaps the problem is that you are not entitled to use it by virtue of not having paid for it?

Comment: I was using hotspot from last 20 days it's just disappeared 2 days back

Answer (score 0):

The same had happened to me (Germany, O2). 
Last year, after I had used the Personal Hotspot (WiFi)once, it disappeared from the menu.
Recently (new iOS, O2 officially supporting the iPhone by now), Personal Hotspot (the bluetooth thing, actually) worked for 2 minutes or so, then went dead. Technically it is still there but I woun't get anything through to the net.

I think it's something like this (not sure though):
The first time you use the personal hotspot, your phone checks with your provider wether it allows to share you mobile internet connection to other devices. If not, it then disables it.
If this is correct, the option should reappear when you purchase a 'shareable' data plan.
May need some kind of reset though, aswell.

Comment: It was working fine for me some days ago

Comment: I was using before without any problem

Comment: Maybe your carrier just introduced the 'feature' of forbidding it only recently?

Comment: It might be but it should not :(

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your Data Roaming (located in Cellular under general settings) is turned on. Once you have done this, you will show your personal hotspot appear.

Answer (score 0):

under cellualr data network, scroll down to internet tethering and write "www" in the APN section. Your personal hotspot will definitly work.

Answer (score 0):

Settings, general, cellular, scroll down, personal hotspot, personal hotspot on. It will re-appear on the first screen. (Settings)

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings > mobile data > mobile data options > mobile data network > here on MOBILE DATA and on PERSONAL HOTSPOT type your network APN ( you can find it on google) then simply go back to the setting menu and restart your phone. It works for me

Answer (score 0):

Go to Cellular -> Cellular Data Options -> Cellular Data Network you will see at the bottom "Personal Hotspot" fields "APN, Username, Password" just put anything and your "Personal Hotspot" will be available in its place.